# Continuous mapping from three sphere $\mathbb{S}^{3}$ onto real number line $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm struggling with a problem that reads as follows,

> Let $f:\mathbb{S}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous mapping. Suppose a point $p\in \mathbb{S}^{3}$ exists such that $f(p)>0$ and that $f^{-1}(0)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{1}$. Show that there are no points $q\in\mathbb{S}^{3}$ such that $f(q)<0$.

I don't have any idea how to tackle this problem, any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch of the argument:
Proceed by contradiction and assume you find a $q\neq p$, such that $f(q)<0$.
Since $f^{-1}(0)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, you can assume, that
$$f^{-1}(0) = \mathbb{S}^1\times \{0\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\times\{0\}\subset \mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4.$$
Since $\mathbb{S}^1$ is one dimensional and $\mathbb{S}^3$ is three dimensional, you find a curve $c:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^3$ (try finding an explicit one!), such that
$$c(0)=p,\ c(1)=q\mbox{ and }c(t)\notin f^{-1}(0)\mbox{ for all }t\in[0,1].$$
Then $f\circ c$ is continuous and we have for all $t\in [0,1]$
$$f\circ c (t) \neq 0.$$
Since $0<f(p)=f(c(0))$ the intermediate value theorem yields $0<f(c(1))=f(q)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: why can we assume that $f^{-1}(0) = S^1 \times \{0\}$? Couldn't $f^{-1}(0)$ be a non-trivial knot in $S^3$?

Comment: You are correct, it could well be a knot of some kind. It does not really matter for the argument though, since the basic idea comes from dimensionality, i.e. in essence $f^{-1}(0)$ is of dimension one, while $\mathbb{S}^3$ is of dimension three, i.e. you can always avoid it via another curve.

Comment: Okay i think that your idea of trying to find $c$ and applying the intermediate value theorem is the key point here. The actual finding of the curve can be done using Jordan-Brouwer Separation theorem, although it won't grant you an explicit curve you at least know it exists due to connectedness of the space. Thanks a lot!